# Swift call same api in different controller

Tags: json, swift, xcode, api

so i dont know if the title is right but i want to call an api that inside controller a in controller b. its because i hit the same api and and i figure i just do this

```
class resetPinVc: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var phoneNumberTextField: SkyFloatingLabelTextField!

 @IBAction func doResetPIn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    loadingProcess(loading: true) // crash here 
    phoneNumberTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    
    resetPinviewModel.doResetPin(mobileNumber: phoneNumberTextField.text ?? "") { [weak self] (resetCode) in //crash here 
        
        if resetCode.code == 200 {
            
            self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "timerSegue", sender: self)
            self?.loadingProcess(loading: false)
            
        }
        else if resetCode.code == 400 {
            
            let message = resetCode.message
            self?.showError(message: message)
            self?.loadingProcess(loading: false)
        }
        else if resetCode.code == 403 {
            let messages = resetCode.message
            self?.showError(message: messages)
            self?.loadingProcess(loading: false)
            self?.phoneNumberTextField.lineColor = UIColor.init(named: COLOR_RED)!
        }
        else if resetCode.code == -99 {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "time out", message: "\(resetCode.code)", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

so i want to call that func that hit api in another controller....which is like this

```
class ResetTimerVc: UIViewController {

 let resetPinVC = resetPinVc()

@IBAction func resend(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let timeFormated = resetPinViewModel.timeFormatted(totalSeconds: totalTime)
    timer?.invalidate()
    totalTime = 60
    timerLabel.text = timeFormated
    
    timerIsOn = false
    
    if timerIsOn == false {
        resendButton.isEnabled = false
        resendButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
        startTimer()
    }
    
    resetPinVC.doResetPIn(resendButton)
}

}
```

but turns out i have a crash (in the line i mention) because apparently i dont have the that loadingProcess func on my ResetTimerVc, and i dont have phoneNumberTextField on my ResetTimerVc as well.

any idea how do i get over this? sorry for the bad english

the reason i need to hit the same api its because i need to hit that api with the same data that i fill in ResetPinVc on ResetTimerVc

thanks.

Comment: What is the declaration type of resetPinviewModel?

Comment: its a string for timer

Comment: you may need to show us the @Class type for resetPinviewModel, and the class interface definition